# Does the run count?

Tags: baseball

Runners on 2nd and 3rd 1 out... the batter hits a drive to the OF and the ball is caught for the 2nd out. the runners advance to home and 3rd base respectively for a sac fly... However, the runner on 2nd left to early and the defense appealed and the umpire called the runner trying to advance to 3rd out for leaving early but the runner on third scored easily before the double play now 8-6-1-4 occurred.. does the run count??? This really happened in my teams game 2 nights ago??

Answer (score 2):

It should count under MLB rules.

The exceptions for a runner reaching the plate not to score are listed in 5.08(a).

- Third out by batter/runner before reaching first
- Third out by any runner in force play
- Third out by a preceding runner failing to touch a base.

The last one doesn't apply because it is a trailing runner that is at fault, and the second doesn't apply because it's not a force play.

I think because scoring an out at a base because of missing or leaving early doesn't require a "tag", some might misinterpret it as a "force" play.

Comment: You can cite an approved ruling on 5.08(b) to support this; the only difference is the doubled-up runner started at 1st, not 2nd.